# Provide a C function with a single argument to get a new function with fewer arguments

Tags: c

I am trying to sort a list points based on their angle relative to a center : 
[image: 1]

I do not care where on the circle the list starts, but it needs to be sorted in a cyclic way. I want to use qsort but it requires a comparison function with only 2 arguments, whereas my comparison function has 3 (the center and the two points to compare) :

```
int compareByAngle(Point *center, Point *lhs, Point *rhs)
{
    return (lhs->x - center->x) * (rhs->y - center->y) - (rhs->x - center->x) * (lhs->y - center->y);
}
```

Do you know how I could get a function with only 2 arguments by supplying the center to another function beforehand? This would be a breeze in a language like haskell but I have no idea how to do it in C, although I know I'd have to use function pointers and arguments - but I'm not very familiar with these techniques.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use your own custom function to sort?

Comment: The `qsort` compare function takes two arguments. In your case these are not actual data, but are pointers to a `struct` and *that* holds the 3 items of information that you need to consider. If your `compare` function returns a non-0 value, `qsort` will use that information to sort the array of structs that you will have passed to it.

Comment: @wrangler this would mean rewriting part of the standard library, which seems unnecessary here

Comment: @Toctave the `compare` function for `qsort` is not in the library. The point is, only you know the sorting criteria, so you have to supply the `compare` function, while `qsort` provides the mechanism.

Comment: You can pass the relative coordinates as function arguments.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, however that would mean putting each element of my list in a struct (or subtracting the centre coordinates), then sorting, then doing it in reverse, which seems time consuming and a bit pointless..

Comment: Well get your data structures right in the first place.

Comment: I mean that if the data is organised in a way that is inconvenient to process, you should consider revising how the data is stored in the first place, rather than trying to force the processing methods. You started by saying you can't use `qsort` because it "only takes two arguments" and now you say it's because you have a (linked?) list.

Comment: glibc provides alternative function -- `qsort_r` which accepts three-argument compare function to handle such sort of problems. Of course, this solution is not portable .

Comment: going back and forth with coordinates computation is quite a common thing, @Toctave. If you think you'd have one coordinate subtraction too much, redefine your data, in polar coordinates perhaps. For comparing  _by angle_ in rectangular system you may need `atan2()`, for which you'd need coordinates relative to your center point.

Comment: As the center point won't change while sorting, you might consider it constant and define it globally. This way it's accessible by the compare function even without being passed as parameter. Not nice, but efficient.

Comment: You can calculate the angle as part of the data structure. Then it does not have to be recalcuated for every sort comparison, and the sort function does not need to know where the centre is.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass configuration data to the comparison function. This is a well-known shortcoming of qsort that generations of C standardisers have failed to address.

There is a non-standard function qsort_r that takes an additional argument, and passes it to the three-arg comparison function. Unfortunately it is not available everywhere, and if it is avaliable, the order of the arguments is not standard.

The only portable way to do this without reworking your data structure is to use a global or static variable:

```
static Point globalCenter;
int compare (void* p1, void* p2) { 
  return compareByAngle(&globalCenter, p1, p2);
}
void myFunc () {
   ...
   globalCenter = center;
   qsort(points, nPoints, sizeof(Point*), compare);
   ...
}
```

It is probably both more efficient and more clear to rework your data structure. How about calculating an array of angles and then sorting it? Then rearrange the points to follow the same order.

Comment: Maybe it's not too bad. You can hide the setting of `globalCenter` and the calling of `qsort()` inside a convenience function. Declaring `globalCenter` just before the function would signal its use (and I would call the global variable something like `CMP_CENTERPOINT` instead).

Answer (score 1):

One quick and dirty way to get it done assuming the pointers lhs and rhs can't be NULL → use a local static variable center initialized with rhs when lhs is NULL :

```
int compareByAngle(Point *lhs, Point *rhs)
{
    static Point *center=NULL;
    if (lhs==NULL) {
        center=rhs;
        return rhs!=NULL; // or any other usefull code
    } else if (center==NULL) {
        // do some error handling
    } else {
        return (lhs->x - center->x) * (rhs->y - center->y) - (rhs->x - center->x) * (lhs->y - center->y);
    }
}
```

Then use it :

```
#define DEFINE_CENTER NULL
...
// first call with NULL as lhs argument and center point as rhs argument
if (compareByAngle(DEFINE_CENTER, center))
    // then use the compare function
    qsort(base, nbmem, size, compareByAngle);
...
```

Or defining a macro like :

```
#define SET_COMP_CENTER(p) compareByAngle(NULL,p)

if (SET_COMP_CENTER(center))
    qsort(....);
```

This solution avoids using a global variable.